# How to change screen within max OSX - Multiple screens - Only with the keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a monitor connected to my 2015 MBP Pro running OSX El Capitan 10.11.3.

I like switching between screens using the `ctrl <-` / `ctrl ->` options.

This is fine most of the time, but say for example that I am currently focused on an application within the external monitor but I would like to switch screens on my MBP. What I tried doing was switching 'focus' to the application currently population the screen of my MBP with the keyboard `cmd tab` and then `ctrl <-` / `ctrl ->`. But this still just moves the screens on the monitor space.

My question is then; how do I switch screens on multiple monitors, without using the mouse / trackpad at all?

By 'switching screens' I mean when you can have multiple windows within OSX, I have 5/6 up at a time on each monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck between a rock & a hard place.

If you set System Prefs > Mission Control to "Displays have separate Spaces" enabled then the Space that will change is the one your mouse cursor is currently in.

If you have that disabled, then both screens will simultaneously change to the same Space, though with potentially different content on each [it's not a mirror, each Space becomes 2 screens wide]

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-screen layout and your 'switch focus then hit ctrl <-' approach works fine on my system.  But maybe the issue is due to laptop being second screen.  Something you could try, but is a bit clunky, is to set up the desktop 'hot corners' (in System Preferences / Desktop / button marked "hot corners in bottom right of window) and put one of them to be "Mission Control".  I've set this to bottom left, and due to offset of the two screens both of them have a 'bottom left' - move mouse to that corner and mission control pops up, and you can choose your window.  Then you can choose which window in either screen simply by clicking.

It is not mouse free - but if keyboard only is important to you simply set Mission Control to a hot key - the default is ctrl-⬆︎ (up arrow) but you could redefine it to something else.